# Caching in JAVA that copes in a weblogic clustered set up

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I'm maintaining a Java web application that uses a java.util.Hashtable to cache values.

This works fine. However when deployed to weblogic under a clustered envrionment this means that I have cache refresh problems due to the fact that (I think) in this set up each node has its own instance of java.util.Hashtable

Is there a way to work around this in a clustered setup. If not can anyone suggest a more robust alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each node will have its own hashmap, that's for sure.

For reliable caching on clustered environment, use some robust solution around, like [JBoss Cache](http://jboss.org/jbosscache) or [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/).